# Mongodb - simple search query to obtain matching keyword

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb in my current project, In this i have a employee searching technique with various possible conditions from a million records in "EMPLOYEES" collection. Currently I have three options for searching critriea

**1. Match at least one word
2. Match all the words
3. Match the exact phrase**

In my database i have to match these keywords with two coloumns "**EMP_FULLNAME**" and "**EMP_FULLALIAS**"

1st condtion to match at least one word, i used this query which returns all the records with atleast one word matching.

```
    db.EMPLOYEES.find({$or :[{"EMP_FULLNAME":/CARLOS|DOS|SANTOS/,
"EMP_FULLALIAS":/CARLOS|DOS|SANTOS/}]})
```

2nd condition to match all the words, i used this query which returns all the records with all the words matching in either of the columns

```
  db.EMPLOYEES.find({$or :[{"EMP_FULLNAME":"CARLOS DOS SANTOS"},
{"EMP_FULLALIAS":"CARLOS DOS SANTOS"}]})
```

3rd condition to match the exact phrase exists in either of the column. -- Need Help with this

Please help with these search criteria to correctly query these conditions in mongodb. i am stuck with these various conditions. Is the search conditions i have created, correct since i have a million records in collection to match.

Comment: For third condition you can you $and condition  db.EMPLOYEES.find({$and :[{"EMP_FULLNAME":"CARLOS DOS SANTOS"},
{"EMP_FULLALIAS":"CARLOS DOS SANTOS"}]}) @deepu

Comment: this will return if name exist in both columns only right..or any of the columns

Comment: Your second condition "Match all the words " is wrong . It is trying to match all phrase in either of column .

Comment: Your second condition has to be like  db.EMPLOYEES.find({$or :[{"$and" : [{"EMP_FULLNAME":{ $regex : /CARLOS/}},
       {"EMP_FULLNAME":{ $regex : /DOS/}},
       {"EMP_FULLNAME":{ $regex : /SANTOS/}}
       ]},{"$and" : [{"EMP_FULLALIAS":{ $regex : /CARLOS/}},
       {"EMP_FULLALIAS":{ $regex : /DOS/}},
       {"EMP_FULLALIAS":{ $regex : /SANTOS/}}
       ]}]});

Comment: thnkz.. i think the second query should be for third condition

Comment: you got it correct ..can i update this in answer

Comment: You should be using a full text search engine. This will not perform well in MongoDb. It will not use indexes.

Comment: Also noting that you have have not accepted you [previous question] on this topic and yet you are **clearly using** that knowledge here. Not to mention the perfectly good regex for what you have explained you were looking for here. It is is not **our** fault if you are theorizing and not asking the questions that will solve your problem. We have suggested alternatives, and asked you to present your use case if you still have problems. Fair practice to give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

Matching all words, use the following regex:

```js
{"$regex": "(?=.*\bCARLOS\b)(?=.*\bDOS\b)(?=.*\bSANTOS\b).+" "$options": "i"}
```

So that means **all** of the words in any order.

And get used to using that syntax for [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). The straight regex form may work in the shell but it is likely you need to use the operator form in most drivers.

The `"$options": "i"` part is for case insensitivity, if that is required

I'm still not sure that this is what you really want as any regex matching is not going to be very performant, as at best you will end up scanning a whole index, and possibly a collection scan.

I think really that you need to present your **actual** use case as a question, in order to get real answers.